# How to apply the formula on a summary field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am developing an inventory system and I have developed the following function to convert between cartons and pieces.

```
Public Function convertQTY(ByVal units_case As Integer, ByVal quantity As QTY) As QTY

    While quantity.pieces < 0 And quantity.cartons > 0

        If quantity.pieces < 0 And quantity.cartons > 0 Then
            quantity.pieces = units_case + quantity.pieces
            quantity.cartons -= 1
        End If

    End While

    If quantity.pieces >= units_case Then

        quantity.cartons = quantity.cartons + (quantity.pieces \ units_case)
        quantity.pieces = quantity.pieces Mod units_case

    End If


    Return quantity
End Function
```

For example if units/pieces per carton is 144 then the above code converts the pieces into cartons if the number exceeds 144 and if the pieces are less than 0 then the above code subtracts 1 from carton and adds units per carton into the number of pieces. So that the pieces never exceed total number of pieces in a carton and they are never shown to be less than 0.

I want the same effect in summary field in my crystal report. For showing sum of cartons and pieces at the end of each group. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you realise that you don't need the While loop inside your code? Just set `quantity.cartons = (quantity.pieces \ units_case)` and then set `quantity.pieces = quantity.pieces Mod units_case` unconditionally, instead.

Answer (score 0):

By creating formulas for the number of cartons and remaining pieces, like so:

`Number Of Cartons:`

```
Sum ({MyTable.Pieces})\144
```

`Remaining Pieces:`

```
Sum ({MyTable.Pieces}) mod 144
```